# check if kvm is used by emulator

Tags: android-studio, kvm

I have kvm installed on my ubuntu 18.04. I have also added my the username to the group. I want to know if the android emulator is using kvm. So I used

```
sudo lsof -n | grep /dev/kvm
```

before and after launching the emulator. Before launching I am getting

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system/run/user/1000/gvfs

      Output information may be incomplete.
```

And after launching the emulator I am getting the above warning but I am also getting this along with that

```
qemu-syst 7854                  nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
qemu-syst 7854 7877             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
qemu-syst 7854 7884             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
QXcbEvent 7854 7890             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
QDBusConn 7854 7891             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
qemu-syst 7854 7898             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7900             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7901             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7902             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7905             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7906             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
threaded- 7854 7907             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7908             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7909             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
qemu-syst 7854 7915             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7921             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7922             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7923             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7925             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7926             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7927             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7928             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7929             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7930             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7931             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7932             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7933             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7934             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7935             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7936             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7937             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7938             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7939             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7940             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7941             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7942             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7943             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7944             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7945             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7946             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7947             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7948             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7949             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7950             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7951             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7952             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7953             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7954             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7955             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7956             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7957             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7958             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7959             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7960             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7961             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7962             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7963             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7964             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7965             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7966             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7967             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7968             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 7969             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
MainLoopT 7854 8006             nik7   29u      CHR             10,232        0t0        464 /dev/kvm
```

So I think the emulator is using kvm but what about that warning. I tried googling but couldn't find an answer

Comment: sudo is not needed for that command since its the user who run the program, its not a problem

Answer (score 1):

The warning is completely irrelevant to KVM or the Android emulator. It occurs because lsof cannot access the [GNOME virtual file system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/38109/20805).

Comment: So what I do then. How do I solve this. I want to get rid of this problem

Comment: @NikhilRathore It's not a problem, and you don't get rid of it. I guess you could switch to KDE or some other DE though. But that's a lot of disruption for something that isn't a problem anyway.